# Web Scraping Returning Blank Value from XPATH

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape ticket prices for a game on stubhub. I was unsuccessful in connecting to the API so I figured I'd use this method instead but am running into some issues...

```
https://www.stubhub.com/chicago-cubs-chicago-tickets-5-3-2021/event/104736306/
```

Why would this XPATH be resulting in a blank value?:

```
price = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.01).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/section[1]/div[1]/ul/div/li[34]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div'))).text
```

larger code snippet:

```
driver.get('https://www.stubhub.com/find/s/?q=chicago%20cubs')
matchups = [i.text for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.EventItem__TitleLink')))]
games = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.EventItem__TitleLink')))]

game_details = pd.DataFrame()
game_details['Matchup'] = matchups
game_details['Link'] = games
print(game_details)

#gather ticket data
urls = []
location = []
prices = []
details = []

for g in games:
    try:
        driver.get(g + '?priceWithFees=true')
        price = [i.text for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.AdvisoryPriceDisplay__content')))]
        price = price[:-2]
        loc = [i.text for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.RoyalTicketListPanel__SectionName')))]
        detail = [i.text for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.RoyalTicketListPanel__SecondaryInfo')))]
        url = [str(g)] * len(price)
        urls.extend(url)
        prices.extend(price)
        location.extend(loc)
        details.extend(detail)
        print(str(g) + ": " + len(price) + " ")
    except:
        print('Failed: ' + str(g))
        pass

ticket_prices = pd.DataFrame()
ticket_prices['Price'] = prices
ticket_prices['Location'] = location
ticket_prices['Detail'] = details
ticket_prices['Link'] = urls

print(ticket_prices.shape)
print(ticket_prices)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(final, engine='xlsxwriter')
game_details.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Games')
ticket_prices.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Tickets')
writer.save()
```

Comment: are you intending to get all prices as there is lazy loading through scrolling on the page.

Comment: I'd love to get all prices, but getting around that lazy loading is step 2 for me.... as of now I'm looking to just get the first to show up

Comment: `prices = [i.text for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 0.01).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.AdvisoryPriceDisplay__content')))]`

Comment: This is still failing about 1/2 the time... Any idea what is causing it to sometimes work vs not? Not sure how I'd troubleshoot that

Comment: perhaps monitor for a change in value instead of presence? First verify if it is a timing issue by adding in waits before. If it is, explore the most reliable wait condition.

Comment: I updated my larger code snippet to my entire code.... any idea why this is randomly failing about half the time? Also happy to ask a new question...